# How to show live camera preview as soon as iOS app launches?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I am following a tutorial on building a camera app here: https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/

It is a simple app with an image view and two buttons, one to take a photo, the other to select a photo from the devices photo library.

So at the moment when I press on the Take Photo button, the camera appears and I can take a picture and so on.

But is there a way to show the live camera preview as soon as the app launches and opens without having to first press Take Photo explicitly? How would I trigger that in viewDidLoad, or elsewhere? Do I need to use AV Foundation?

At the moment my program is using the image picker controller to present the camera to the user using this code:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the short answer but yes, you need to use AVFoundation. There is no decent way to embed the `UIImagePickerController` to your view.

You could, of course, use `-[UIViewController addChildViewController:]` and then add the imagePickers view as subview into your viewController:

```
[[self view] addSubview:[pickerVC view]];

[self addChildViewController:pickerVC];
[pickerVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

But to be honest, you might better implement the camera using `AVFoundation`, as the approach above might seem kinda "hackish" nowadays, as I personally think. Also you'd need to properly deal with auto layout and I don't really know, if the `UIImagePickerViewController` in particular likes to be treated like this.
Keep in mind that these components are built for specific use cases and to serve a special purpose, not as usual subclassable, open solution like `UIViewController`